# Word for the collectively leadership and important roles in a society

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I am seeking a term for what can collectively be referred to as "the leader and/or the most important and powerful roles" in the hierarchy of a society.

I have an example from the YA series *Warrior Cats* by Erin Hunter.

[image]

Warriors are the generic members of society. Meanwhile Leader, Deputy, and Medicine Cat together are the important and powerful positions. A term, for them together, as a collective, is what I seek so I can quickly an efficiently refer to them instead of some nickname like "the Big Three" every single time.

I would like for a term generally applicable to most of societies, as it can be used in many contexts. I've been unable to think of any possibilities, hence I ask.

Example Sentence: "The X are foundational to how our clan runs."

Comment: It kind of depends if they're a long-lasting ruling caste/strata, or if they're chosen from the masses; and if they meet together to rule the clan or separately have power because of a larger system; if you just want a name for a group of roles, or for them meeting or acting together, or for the people behind the roles. Ruling class, aristocracy, gentry, patriciate, leadership, establishment, vanguard, authority/authorities, cabinet, board of governors. Or just a plural like leaders, bigwigs, chiefs, directors, bosses, head honchos, brahmins...

Comment: @StuartF "Vanguard" hits me like lightning. It's single word; the meaning is straightforward,  clear, and generally neutral, nor does it come with any preconceived notions or contations attached to it. It's perfect for an answer. So are similar words, if findable.

Comment: @TinfoilHat That's more a synonym for king/ruler.

Comment: @TinfoilHat:  *Sovereignty* usually means the supreme authority possessed by someone;  I don't think it's usually used to mean the agent(s) who possess(es) the authority itself (except perhaps by some sort of poetic metonymy.)  And *sovereign* definitely has more of a connotation of a single person, since it denotes someone with supreme power over all others (i.e., "the buck stops here".)

Comment: Nonwarriors, or The Clawless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibilities are Diverse in nature.

Here are my Contributions :

> [triumvirate](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=triumvirate)
>
> > A group of three men responsible for public administration or civil authority
> > Alternative : [troika](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=troika)

> [coterie](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=coterie)
>
> > Exclusive circle of people with a common purpose
> > Alternatives : clique , inner circle

> [high command](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=high%20command)
>
> > highest leaders
> > Alternative : top brass

> [core group](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=core%20group)
>
> > small group of indispensable persons or things
> > Alternative : [nucleus](https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=nucleus)

Comment: Coterie is excellent, thank you.

Comment: @Rewan On [another answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/609113/2587), you mention you’re unhappy with *elite* because of its connotations of corruption and colsedness.  At least to my ear, *coterie* has much stronger connotations of these.

Answer (score 10):

The ***elite*** in a society are those at the top of the sociological structure who hold a disproportionate amount of power, influence, or wealth. These may be people who hold particular offices or specific roles as leaders, but may also include unofficial roles of power like that of a very wealthy businessperson. It's an excellent fit to generally describe people in the highest levels of society, but isn't strictly limited to those in codified positions.

Comment: While technically correct, "elite" often comes with notions of corrupt and closed off, not exactly respect or formality.

Comment: @RewanDemontay Do you feel the same connotation for "elite athletes"?

Comment: @dubious No, but in this case the needed context is given by the word "athletes". I am specifically looking for a term, which are generally neutral in implications, that does not require additional context, that can used on its own and have its meaning known through a single word.

Comment: @RewanDemontay I certainly agree the term can be used in a vaguely pejorative sense, especially in the modern political context referring to "rich people you shouldn't like". But it may be a neutral or positive term depending on the context - there will be a connotation of corruption for elites who rise to the top through corrupt means, but not for elites who rise to the top through their own merits.

Answer (score 10):

In this specific case, the common word **leaders** fits the bill; *or*, more formally, [the] **leadership** can be used.

“Leadership” is probably more common as a noun for the quality of *being* a leader, but it also has the meaning of referring to a group who are in charge:

- **leadership** (n.) the person or people in charge of an organization ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/leadership))

Comment: E.g. "Thunderclan leadership met on Tuesday" is perfectly fine

Answer (score 4):

This perhaps should fit the bill— **movers and shakers**

> The **movers and shakers** in a place or area of activity are the people who have most power or influence.

*It is the movers and shakers of the record industry who will decide which bands make it.*

[*Collins Dictionary*]

Comment: Though excellent, this is more of a phrase than a word.

Answer (score 3):

'Hierarchy' itself carries this sense:

> **[the] hierarchy** ...
>
> (3) the upper echelons of a hierarchical system. {noun: the hierarchy}
>
> - *the magazine was read quite widely even by some of the hierarchy*

[Oxford Languages; Dictionary seen on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=hierarchy+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=&aqs=chrome.1.69i59i450l8.680152671j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)]

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hierarchy) has:

> **hierarchy**: the people in the upper levels of an organization who control it

Comment: Context is important for this one, as it can refer to the entire structure itself, or to the members of the upper levels of the structure. Putting it into the OP's example sentence ("The hierarchy is foundational to how our clan runs"), I would interpret it to mean that the layered class structure as a whole is important, not only the people at the top.

Comment: This answer is actually the original meaning of “hierarchy” (from Greek, meaning “rule by a priesthood”), but that sense of the word has very much fallen out of use, except when specifically talking about religious organisations.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most neutral word for the group you are describing is simply "leaders" (or "leadership").

But if you are looking for a natural word to be used in-universe for a small number of individuals who are the leaders of a fairly small traditional community, "leaders" may seem too generic. Perhaps "council"? That suggests they meet with some regularity, so, if they don't, then it's probably not so good.

Another possibility is "elders". If necessary you could explain that they don't actually have to be old, but the term is a holdover from the past where the leaders would actually be older. And probably they would still be older on average than the rest because it takes time to earn a position.

A final possibility is to make up a word. If it's a very well-defined leadership group, maybe there's not a good English word, and so you would just adopt the word they used in their language.

Answer (score 1):

A word that comes to mind is [**aristocracy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristocracy_(class)).

From the Wikipedia link:

> The aristocracy[1] is historically associated with "hereditary" or "ruling" social class. In many states, the aristocracy included the upper class of people (aristocrats) with hereditary rank and titles.[2] In some, such as ancient Greece, ancient Rome, or India, aristocratic status came from belonging to a military class. It has also been common, notably in African societies, for aristocrats to belong to priestly dynasties.

The word can, in certain contexts, have a negative connotation (the French Revolution sought to abolish the whole concept of aristocracy...) but depending on the context you are looking for, it may be a(n almost) perfect fit.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a number of words that might fit the bill, depending on the connotation you want.

One word that maybe encompasses all the categories below (and probably my #1 choice) is

- **overseer**: *(n) a person who oversees others : a person with supervisory responsibilities*

Other words, based on different leadership responsibilities:

- Responsible for guiding the clan, and making wise decisions:

  - **steward**
  - **shepherd**
  - **guide**
- Responsible for administration and making sure society runs smoothly:

  - **governor**
  - **administrator**
  - **authority**
  - **manager**
- Responsible for protection and safety:

  - **guardian**
  - **protector**
  - **supervisor**

If you look for [synonyms of overseer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/overseer), you might find other words that work for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

The [establishment](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Establishment) seems like a reasonable fit here, if it isn't too British for you.

Answer (score 0):

The closest fit I can think of is **upper echelons**, referring to the "ranking members" of society; those that the minions report to.

See this entry from [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/echelon):

```
Noun. A level of command, authority, or rank:
"After years of service, she is now in the
upper echelon of city officials."
```

Or my favorite example from [Star Trek: The Original Series](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Mark_of_Gideon_(episode)), after Spock violates the "prime directive":

> Your Excellency, please do not interfere. I already have one serious
> problem to resolve with upper echelons.
>
> – Spock's parting words to Hodin, "The Mark of Gideon"